# react-create-app test set default headers

Tags: reactjs, testing

I'm using [react-create-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) for my application. For tests I would need to set global headers for requests.. So when I'm caling REST API, I could send test users to REST API. I would like to set headers per test based, or globally.

I read react-create-app is using Jest for running tests, also jsdom. I wonder if is it possible to manipulate headers for test purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to set headers globally before run any of your tests, you can simply add a [`src/setupTests.js`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#initializing-test-environment) to your react-create-app project and set the default headers in that file. For set default headers before running any test in the current file, you can use jest [`beforeAll`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#beforeallfn) method.

The way you set default headers is entirely based on the API or library that you use to call your Rest APIs.

As an example, if you use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to call your API, you can set default headers globally in `src/setupTests.js` with the following code.

**`src/setupTests.js`**

```javascript
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.headers.common['my-default-header'] = 'my-default-value';
```

If you are using JavaScript [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) use [fetch-intercept](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-intercept)

```javascript
import fetchIntercept from 'fetch-intercept';

const unregister = fetchIntercept.register({
    request: function (url, config) {
        const withDefaults = Object.assign({}, config);
        withDefaults.headers = defaults.headers || new Headers();
        withDefaults.headers.append('my-default-header', 'my-default-value');
        return [url, withDefaults];
    }
});
```